# Variable meta description

Tags: php, html, include

In the site I'm working on, I have header & footer includes. I'd like to be able to a different meta description on each page of the site, but it's baffling me. The title works fine, but I'm wondering if this is because there are quotation marks involded.

header.php code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">  
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $desc; ?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="neurologist, neurologic, neurology, nervous system, brain, seizure, epilepsy, carpal tunnel, seattle, ballard, washington, wa, king county, swedish hospital">
```

index.php code is:

```
<?php include ("header.php"); ?>
<?php $title = "Neurologic Clinic | Dr. Hal Rappaport | Seattle Neurologist"; ?>
<?php $desc = "Dr. Hal Rapport is a neurologist located in Seattle's Ballard neighborhood. He specializes in neurologic conditions and disorders and is also a certified psychologist"; ?>
```

Any help you can give is appreciated.

Comment: Include the header **after** you assign to `$title` and `$desc`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are assigning your variables after include header, so change to

```
<?php $title = "Neurologic Clinic | Dr. Hal Rappaport | Seattle Neurologist"; ?>
<?php $desc = "Dr. Hal Rapport is a neurologist located in Seattle's Ballard neighborhood. He specializes in neurologic conditions and disorders and is also a certified psychologist"; ?>
<?php include ("header.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, **Define** `$title`, `$desc`. Then **Include** Header

```
<?php
    $title = "title";
    $desc = "description";

    include("header.php");
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to call `<?php ?>` in every line.

```
<?php
$title = "Neurologic Clinic | Dr. Hal Rappaport | Seattle Neurologist";
$desc = "Dr. Hal Rapport is a neurologist located in Seattle's Ballard neighborhood. He specializes in neurologic conditions and disorders and is also a certified psychologist";
include ("header.php");
?>
```